# Unexplained margin in Auto Layout

Tags: ios, autolayout

Pretty simple really. I've got a yellow scrollView that contains a blue view. In the xib, I've set the blue view to totally fill its parent (the scrollView), by matching all their borders with 0 offset:
[image: Xib Editor]

And yet, here it is at execution:
[image]

At this point, I've stripped down the code to its strict minimum to isolate the cause of the error, and I'm left with *nothing left in my code*. I tried setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to NO and calling `layoutIfNeeded` for all views, it doesn't change anything. Do you guys have any idea where this space on the top comes from?

Answer (score 0):

The contentInset is affected by the (height of the) navigation bar.

Try setting `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;`

This can also be set in the storyboard with `'Adjust Scroll View Insets'`.